# Ordenar filas iguais

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

Eu tenho 4 colunas no excel: A,B,C,D certo?
Só que eu preciso ordenar para realizar uma comparação pois está toda a informação desorganizada me explico:

**Arquivo Original em .CSV (Informação desorganizada )**

```
 A(Inglês)         B (Tradução)             C(Inglês)                D (Trad.)
    "xxx.yyy.Hello"            "Oi"        "xxx.yyy.Text"         Texto
    "xxx.yyy.Green"            "Verde"     "xxx.yyy.Hello"        Hello
```

**Como gostaria que ficasse assim:**

```
   A(Inglês)         B (Tradução)             C(Inglês)                D (Trad.)
"xxx.yyy.Hello"            "Oi"             "xxx.yyy.Hello"        "Hello"  
"xxx.yyy.Green"            "Verde"           "xxx.yyy.Text"         "Texto"
```

Resumindo **devem ser iguais os valores dos campos A e C,** pra ficar mais fácil de realizar a comparação das traduções.

Observação: O arquivo contém aprox 4000 linhas em cada fila (A,B,C,D).
Existe forma de realizar esse tipo de ordenação no excel, plugin, etc...
Desde já obrigado!!!

Comment: Não era melhor estruturar o ficheiro com apenas 2 colunas ? Inglês e tradução ? Ou 3 colunas se quiser duas traduções

Comment: acontece que eu tenho 2 arquivos .csv entende? 
dae eu vou tentar colocar eles desse jeito que te falei.
Arquivo 1 teria as colunas A e B , Arquivo 2 as colunas C  e D

Comment: Mas está a tentar juntar os dois arquivos num só ? Juntando as entradas que existem nos dois ?

Comment: Mas como farei isso se as palavras estão todas embaralhadas? fazer isso manualmente levaria horas.... 
Lembre-se que são quase 4000 linhas

Comment: E porque não a ferramenta de remover duplicados? Que já daria para colocar todos seguidos na mesma planilha e remover duplicados

Comment: me explico : os campos A  e C são códigos informáticos, só que eu quis fazer mais didaticamente aqui, mais vamos lá:

Campo A              Campo C
xxx.yyy.Green     xxx.yyy.Green
@danieltakeshi

Comment: @RodrigoHackzExploitz Você possui alguma experiência em Excel VBA? Ou isso deve ser realizado somente com fórmulas e ferramentas padrão?

Comment: Não sou programador..... sempre atuei em suporte..... minhas noções de programação são bem basicas e faz muitos anos q não compilo nada..... rsrsrss

Comment: Sugiro colocar o exemplo das folhas originais e do que pretende fazer, o objetivo final. Isso parece me um [problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/499/o-que-%C3%A9-o-problema-xy)

Comment: @Isac , não sei se fará diferença mais editei exatamente como estão os campos originais.
São códigos de um arquivo .json que eu passei pro .csv e posteriormente passei em excel.
Observação: as colunas ( A  e B )  pertencem ao arquivo1.csv 
                     as colunas (  C e D )  pertencem ao arquivo2.csv
entende?

Comment: @RodrigoHackzExploitz Sabe se há duplicatas da mesma palavra em cada arquivo csv? Se houver, só consigo pensar em VBA para resolver o problema.

Comment: existem com certeza..... pois minha ideia é comparar os campos traduzidos e os que ainda estão sem traduzir.@danieltakeshi

Comment: E como sabe quais os que estão por traduzir ?

Comment: Verificando os campos B e D, saberei se foram traduzidos ou não.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sugiro utilizar a formula `PROCV`. Pode construir uma folha com as seguintes colunas:

```
Referencia | Tradução PT | Tradução EN
```

Algo como:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em que a `Tradução PT` e `Tradução EN` são obtidas através de uma procura na folha/documento onde estão. As referências sendo coincidentes nas duas folhas bastaria copiar de uma delas e colar nesta nova folha.

Para a `Tradução PT` utilizaria a formula:

```
=PROCV(A2;Folha2!$A$1:$B$4;2;FALSO)
```

Em que `A2` é a referencia e `Folha2!$A$1:$B$4` é a folha com as traduções em Português. Visualmente a folha de traduções em português ficaria assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Note que a ordem das referências nesta folha é irrelevante pois os valores são obtidos por procura.

Para a `Tradução EN` a formula seria igual mas noutra folha:

```
=PROCV(A2;Folha3!$A$1:$B$4;2;FALSO)
```

Com isto consegue rapidamente ver quais estão em falta. Pode inclusivamente fazer uma formula ao lado para lhe indicar sempre que uma tradução está em falta assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em que o campo `Em falta` utiliza a formula:

```
SE(B2=C2;"FALTA";"")
```

Que apenas compara se ambas as traduções são iguais e se forem diz que a tradução está em falta.

Com isto consegue filtrar pelos que faltam simplificando consideravelmente o manuseamento da folha. Pode até saber quantas traduções estão em falta no total, com uma formula como `=CONTAR.SE(D2:D5;"FALTA")` especificando como intervalo os valores todos para a coluna `Em falta`.

Comment: agradeço sua ajuda.... mais os dados do campo A  e C são iguais com códigos ( xxx.yyy.Palavra)... outra coisa que eles estão embaralhados, não estão certinhos como vc colocou na foto, por isso tem que primeiro ordenar... pra ficar tudo na mesma fila, e isso é o complexo pra mim, entende?

Comment: @RodrigoHackzExploitz No exemplo que eu dei a ordem não tem relevancia, pode ser a que quiser, pode até ordenar pela referência, pois as duas colunas ao lado obtêm o valor correspondente através de procura.

Comment: Agradeço muito mesmo! irei realizar uns testes e darei o retorno :)

Answer (score 0):

É possível realizar o que foi pedido por fórmulas do Excel.

#### Dados de Entrada

[image: Dados Amostra]

#### Resultado

[image: Resultado]

### Como fazer?

Foram inseridas novas fórmulas nas colunas F,G,H e I para comparar as duas colunas e retornar na mesma linha quando houver palavras iguais

#### Coluna F

```
=SE($H1="";"";A1)
```

#### Coluna G

```
=SE($H1="";"";B1)
```

#### Coluna H

```
=SE(É.NÃO.DISP(CORRESP(A1;C:C;0));"";ÍNDICE(C:C;CORRESP(A1;C:C;0)))
```

#### Coluna I

```
=SE($H1="";"";ÍNDICE(D:D;CORRESP(A1;C:C;0)))
```

#### Problema

> Quando houver duplicatas no segundo arquivo, não funcionará do modo que está descrito.

Portanto a sugestão para corrigir este problema (se houver) é olhar este [link](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2017/02/22/vlookup-multiple-values-excel/)

Comment: agradeço muito sua ajuda.
1) Mais teria que fazer essa forma manualmente acredito pra as 4000 linhas? isso seria muito tempo... ou entendi errado?
2) A ideia seria "não perder " conteúdo dos dados como aparece...
ficou 1 fila menos.

Comment: 1) Não precisa realizar manualmente, somente usar o `.Autofill` clicando duas vezes no canto direito inferior da primeira célula, em que há um quadrado preto. 2) Bom, esta fórmula somente alinha o que for igual no arquivo 1 e 2, palavras que são únicas não aparecem. Verificar o link que passei se quiser alterar sua planilha para algo mais flexível e completo.

Comment: Se tiver alguém lendo ainda.....

Seria muito dificil realizar isto com alguma linguagem de programação tipo Python, Java, C# ???? ... dizem que Python é mais simples....
Pois acredito que esta questão verei em outras ocasiões.

Comment: @RodrigoHackzExploitz Eu acho o Excel VBA fácil e todas outras alternativas também podem ser usadas. Mas se o seu conhecimento de programação não atende as necessidades, sugiro utilizar softwares de tradução prontos como o POedit e o Transifex (estes dois mais comuns para sites e bases com PHP). Basta dar uma pesquisada para encontrar muitos outros.